# Is it possible to post to facebook in comment plug-in on the web page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, backend

Is it possible to post to facebook in comment plug-in on the web page with graph api or other api.Which developed with go language.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API to post comments on an external Open Graph object.

The plugin itself allowed “comment mirroring” for a while, where comments posted under an external URL would also show under a Facebook post about that URL, and vice versa - but Facebook has got rid of that again by now.